# Mixed domain: how to setup password referral

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm working with a mixture of linux and windows servers and am hoping to use AD to tie in to a centralized LDAP authentication process.

I recently installed a Windows 2012 R2 server as a domain controller. I have the LDAP info to access our company's LDAP server but haven't yet found out how to setup the password referral process. People have suggested using OpenDJ or OpenLDAP instead but I figured I would at least *try* using the native applications to get this setup. After many hours of reading and looking about I'm thinking this isn't going to work.

Suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Summary: I have some equipment in **subdom.company.com**. There is an LDAP server at **ldap.company.com** that is available for authentication if I can only get my domain connected / pointed to it. Should I continue with Windows 2012 R2 or switch to Samba? Some other avenue?

---

UPDATE: Until recently our equipment was almost entirely CentOS/Debian. We used NIS to maintain accounts and all was well. Now we're adding more windows clients and have the opportunity to get all of our authentication handled by the servers of the larger company. IE No more need to set these up on each file server (via samba) for windows clients.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your LDAP server to authenticate your Windows users and computers rather than your AD Domain Controller authenticating them or are you looking for some kind of Single Sign On solution?

Comment: Single sign on. All the relevant accounts exist on LDAP.COMPANY.COM. I'd like to be able to use them on all machines in *.SUBDOM.COMPANY.COM. I have been provided with a (probably dated) list of LDAP credentials to use but I don't see how to set this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little unclear on what you mean by "password referral". I *think* you're saying that you want Active Directory to authenticate users against the LDAP directory hosted by your "ldap.company.com" server.

Assuming that's the case: There isn't functionality in Active Directory to do what you're looking for. Active Directory is (among other things) a Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) backed by LDAP-accessible directory. It's functionally similar to your existing LDAP directory. It has no functionality to "proxy" authentication to another LDAP directory.

You *can* create trust relationships with other Kerberos Realms. If you have another Kerberos implementation that back-ends to your existing LDAP directory you can create a realm trust between your new Active Directory and the realm. This would allow security principals from the Kerberos realm to be granted access to resources in the Active Directory forest / domain.

Like I said, it's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish. You may well be better off just using Samba to back-end authentication to your LDAP servers if you don't want / need all the functionality that Active Directory duplicates. (If you'll provide some more narrative on what you're trying to do I can expand this answer.)

Edit:

Based on your edit I can tell you that Active Directory won't do what you're looking for. You can't offload authentication from AD to another LDAP directory. It just won't do that.

If I were in your situation I'd probably [create a Kerberos realm back-ending to your LDAP directory](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html), join the Windows clients to the new Active Directory domain, create a realm trust between the Active Directory domain and the Kerberos realm, then finally [configure the Windows clients to allow SSO with Kerberos credentials.](http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/services/iam/kerberos/ad-xrt-howto.xml?ID=the-procedure#proc-client-config)